# Ember route with dynamic segment name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm just starting with Ember JS and Ember CLI and trying to figure out this routing issue. I have a group model that has many game models. With the following route, I am able to display games just fine from a group URL:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("groups", function() {
    this.route('show', {path: ':group_id/show' });
  });
});
```

This results in a URL with the form:

```
http://localhost:4200/groups/1/show
```

Suppose one of the group names is "wizards". I'd like to to be able to construct a URL in the following form and render all the games that belong to "wizards":

```
 http://localhost:4200/wizards
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Why not add a new route like this.route('group', {path: ':group_name' }); inside the groups resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @blessenm points out in the comments, your router would change from

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("groups", function() {
    this.route('show', {path: ':group_id/show' });
  });
});
```

to

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("group", { path: ':group_name'});
});
```

The second parameter to `this.resource()` or `this.route()` is optional. If you don't pass anything in - it assumes the same name as your route/resource (groups, in your case). If you pass in an object that has a `path:` key - you are specifying what the url to the route is, including a dynamic segment. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) for Ember documentation on this.